# CentOS 6.5 PHP extensions

Tags: centos, centos-6

I need to enable php extensions like `PDO` and `GD` but I can't find a section with all the PHP extensions enabled inside `/etc/php.ini`, so in which file is this defined?

**EDIT**: using **PHP Version 5.5.14** or so `phpinfo();` says

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850805), you may need to check the "Loaded Configuration File" and perhaps the "additional .ini files parsed" sections. This should tell you what files are being used specifically for Apache, assuming that is your goal. Otherwise, [php --ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini) might do the trick if you are interested in the (likely separate) command line php .ini.

If you don't have a loaded configuration file for Apache, you may want to see this question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out each extension has it's `*.ini` file under `/etc/php.d/`